# typedef pointer alias vs define pointer alias

Tags: c, typedef

When you declare a pointer to int:

```
int *a, b;
```

`a` is a pointer to `int` whereas `b` is an `int` (I've never really understood why this happens, I know is related to the comma but I used to say that the asterisk is binned to the variable name instead of data type). Anyway, if you:

```
#define intptr int*
intptr a, b
```

The result is the same. The fact that I find weird is why using `typedef` for the same thing changes the behavior?

```
typdef int* intptr 
intptr a, b;
```

*In the last example I was expecting `a` to be an `int*` whereas `b` an `int`. Instead, they are both `int*`*

---

For clarification, having the following code snippet I don't understand why I don't get the same warning for the **`d`** variable

```
#define intptr_def int*

typedef int* intptr_typ;

int main()
{
    int x;

    intptr_def a, b;
    intptr_typ c, d;

    a = &x;
    b = &x;     // Warning assignment to 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast
    c = &x;
    d = &x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A typedef is not the same as a macro.  A typedef gives an alias to a type.  A macro does text substitution.  If you study the standard carefully (C11 [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) — a long section), you'll see that a declaration has two parts — the 'declaration specifiers' which specify the base type (`int` etc, but nor modifiers for pointer or array or function types), and the 'init-declarator list' which contains a comma-separated list of the individual declarators.  The declarators include decorations for pointer, array and function types.

Comment: Try adding a space between `int` and `*` in the macro (i.e. `#define intptr int *`), then "expand" the declaration: It expands to `int *a, b;` which is what you previously had.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The space between `int` and `*` is immaterial — there are two tokens (`int` and `*`) regardless of the spacing around them.

Comment: And in declaration the pointer-maker asterisk binds to the next variable. Which means `int* a, b;`, `int * a, b;` and `int *a, b;` all mean the same thing: It's `a` which is the pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know, I mean for it to be easier to "see" the expanded macro being the same as the first declaration.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler regarding your first answer, so you basically say that when using `typedef` it's almost like I create a new type `int*` which applies to all variables separated by comma instead of the case of `int* a, b` where the star was just bind to the first variable?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu — to a first approximation, yes.  For example, if you create a typedef for a function pointer type, such as `typedef void *(*function)(const char *str, int index);`, then you can later define a variable of the type, such as `function funcptr;`, without embedding all the notation.  That is equivalent to writing `void *(*funcptr)(const char *str, int index);`.  If you've got to do that more than about once, the typedef becomes easier to understand (and type).

Comment: If you want a macro for that, you'd have to write `#define FUNCPTR(name) void *(*(name))(const char *str, int index)`.  You'd have to use that one per definition — `FUNCPTR(funcptr1); FUNCPTR(funcptr2);` — whereas with the typedef, you could write `function funcptr1, funcptr2;` (though it's easily arguable that you shouldn't do that).

Comment: pfu...kind of had for me to understand the example you provided it's a little bit too complicated for me

Comment: Another way to avoid the confusion is to understand [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). (hint: No)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro is a text substitution, nothing more.  If you have

```
#define intptr int*
```

and write

```
intptr a, b;
```

then when the code is preprocessed, the `intptr` macro is *expanded* to

```
int* a, b;
```

which is processed exactly the same as

```
int *a, b;
```

and only declares `a` as a pointer; `b` is a regular `int`.

A typedef name is an *alias* for a type - it’s not a text substitution like the preprocessor macro.

```
typedef int *intptr;
```

creates `intptr` as an alias for `int *` (pointer to `int`).
So when you write

```
intptr a, b;
```

both `a` and `b` have type `intptr` (`int *`).

---

Declarations in C have the basic structure

```
declaration-specifiers declarators
```

Declaration specifiers include type specifiers (`int`, `float`, `char`, etc.), type qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`), storage class specifiers (`static`, `auto`, `register`), and a few other specifiers related to function declarations/definitions.

A *declarator* introduces the name of the thing being declared, along with information about that thing’s array-ness, pointer-ness, and function-ness.  For example, in the declaration

```
static volatile unsigned int a[10], *p;
```

the declaration specifiers are `static volatile unsigned int` and the declarators are `a[10]` and `*p`.  The type of each variable is fully specified by the combination of the declaration specifiers and the declarator.  The type of `a` is "10-element array of `static volatile unsigned int`" and the type of `p` is "pointer to `static volatile unsigned int`".

The idea is that the structure of the declarator matches the structure of the expression in the code.  For example, suppose you have a pointer to an `int` named `iptr`, and you want to print the value in the object it points to, you’d write

```
printf( "%d\n", *iptr );
```

The type of the expression `*iptr` is `int`, so the declaration is written as

```
int *iptr;
```

You can also write it as

```
int* iptr;
```

or

```
int*iptr;
```

or even

```
int      *      iptr;
```

and all will be interpreted as

```
int (*iptr);
```

Whitespace doesn’t make any difference - the `*` is always part of the declarator, not the declaration specifiers.  Declarators can get arbitrarily complex - for any sequence of declaration specifiers `T`, you can have

```
T x;          // x is an object of type T
T a[N];       // a is an array of T
T *p;         // p is a pointer to T
T f();        // f is a function returning T

T *a[N];      // a is an array of pointer to T
T (*p)[N];    // p is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();       // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*p)();     // p is a pointer to a function returning T

T *(*a[N])(); // a is an array of pointers to functions
              // returning pointer to T
```

and that just barely scratches the surface.